# how to use React query cache

Tags: reactjs, typescript, caching, react-query, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm trying to create a website where you fetch metrics and dimensions from the nodejs server using react query displaying them in a list then imply drag and drop on that list to drag an element and drop it in a zone. The problems I'm facing is that first I must Have a global state which I already figured it out by calling useQuery again with the same key . The other problem is idk if I have to modify the react query cache(by setQueryData) or directly the fetched data by the useQuery Hook(wouldn't that cause bugs?). Also another question is it the cache that is being used to render the html or no? I'm kind of new to these things...

here is the custom Hook for fetching data:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

const useMetadata = (kind:string) => {
    return useQuery(
        `properties-${kind}`,
        () => {
          return axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/ga/${kind}`)
        })
}

export default useMetadata
```

Here is the list of metrics/dimensions :

```
import { Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import Property from "./Property";
import Spinner from "../../../utils/Spinner/Spinner";
import useMetadata from "../../../hooks/useMetadata";
type Props ={
  kind: 'metrics' | 'dimensions';
}
type metadataType = {
  uiName:string,
  name:string,
  description:string,
  _id:string,
}
const Properties = (props: Props) => {
  const { kind } = props;
  const { data, isLoading, error } =  useMetadata(props.kind);
  const metadata = data?.data.data.metadata.map((item:metadataType, index: number) => {
    let property;

    property = (
      <Property index={index} id={item._id} key={index} name={item.uiName} />
    );

    return property;
  });

  return (
    <div className=" flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full">
          <h3 className=" text-2xl font-semibold">{kind}</h3>

    {isLoading? <Spinner/>: <div className="flex w-full justify-around items-center">
    <Droppable droppableId="Properties">
      {(provided) => (
        <ul ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps} className=" list-none overflow-y-scroll h-96 flex flex-col justify-center items-center font-semibold">
          {metadata}
          {provided.placeholder}
        </ul>

      )}


    </Droppable>
    <Droppable droppableId="PickedProperties">
      {(provided) => (
        <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps} className=" w-96 h-44 border-2 border-cyan-600 flex justify-center items-center">
          {provided.placeholder}

        </div>
      )}

    </Droppable>

  </div>}
  </div>
    
  );
};

export default Properties;
```

And here where I'm trying to implement the drop functionality :

```
import Aside from "../Aside/Aside";
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { DragDropContext, DropResult } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import useMetadata from "../../hooks/useMetadata";
import { queryClient } from "../../main";
interface Props {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}
const Layout: React.FC = (props: Props) => {
  
  const {data: metrics}= useMetadata('metrics');
  const {data: dimensions}= useMetadata('dimensions');
  const setMetrics=(metrics:any)=>{
    queryClient.setQueryData('metrics',(metrics)=>{
      // the code responsible for the dropping I guess...
    })
  }
  const onDragEnd=(result:DropResult)=>{
    const {destination, source}=result;
    if(!destination) return;
    if(destination.droppableId===source.droppableId&&destination.index===source.index) return;
    // the code responsible for dropping I guess x2 ....
  }
  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <div className=" box-border p-0 m-0 w-full h-screen overflow-y-hidden flex bg-gray-100  text-gray-700">
        <Aside />
        <div className="w-full">
          <Header />
          <main className="flex justify-center items-center h-full w-full">
            <Outlet />
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    </DragDropContext>

  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Comment: Are you also sending the drag n drop changes back to the server using a mutation?

Comment: @JakubKotrs no I'm not. I don't think it's necessary

Comment: In general terms, react-query is used to handle async (server) state, so unless you are also mutating the data back, you may run into the issue that the query *reruns* when it becomes stale and the user would lose any changes made. So, if you were storing the changes back to backend, modifying the query cache is the way forward (as a callback of the mutation). If not, it may be preferable to copy the data to local state and not modifying query cache. I may try to write a full answer with this later if I find the time. ;)

Comment: @JakubKotrs sorry for the late response . so you mean if you want to manipulate the data fetched on the client side it's better to save it to local state ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it would have been a big answer and I just can't find the time to structure it properly. TLDR: if you want to mutate data locally without sending it back to the server to sync it, it's better to copy the data into local state. Otherwise you risk that the query might re-run which would result in the user losing all changes. You may keep it in the cache despite this if you make sure you set up cacheTime, staleTime, refetches and other stuff to never re-run the query, but it may introduce other issues as well.